# conditional replacement in dplyr

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have a Data Set with years and weeks

dput of data

```
structure(list(ww_cal = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 
52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 
46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L), yy_cal = c(2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L)), .Names = c("ww_cal", "yy_cal"), row.names = 3000:4000, class = "data.frame")
```

What I'm trying to do is the following conditional

if the max value of week for each year is 53, then ww_2 = ww_cal-1 if not ww_2 = ww_cal

That way every year will have 52 weeks.

Here's the code I'm using but without the desired results

```
df2 = df1 %>%
    group_by(yy_cal) %>%
    mutate(df2 = ifelse(max(ww_cal) == 53, ww_cal-1, ww_cal))
```

It outputs

> Error: incompatible types, expecting a integer vector

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Because the columns are `integer`, dplyr expects you to use `ww_cal-1L`

Comment: @docendodiscimus didn't think of it!! Thanks! Now I'm facing another problem, because the new column outputs 1 in every single cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually two problems in your code:

- Problem 1: `df1$ww_cal` is an integer and you need to subtract an integer from it (as was pointed out by [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus).
- Problem 2: You are using `ifelse()` in a wrong way.

Solutions to both problems are described below:

#### Problem 1

This was already solved by [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3521006/docendo-discimus) in a comment and I only repeat his solution here to make the answer complete.

The column `ww_cal` has class integer:

```
class(df1$ww_cal)
## [1] "integer"
```

When you subtract `1`, the class of the result is numeric. To have an integer as a result, you need to explicitly subtract the *integer* `1L`:

```
class(df1$ww_cal - 1)
## [1] "numeric"
class(df1$ww_cal - 1L)
## [1] "integer"
```

Note that it is not forbidden to subtract `1` (there is no error message when you run the first line of code above). It just seems that `dplyr` does not allow you to change the class of data frame columns that you manipulate.

#### Problem 2

The second problem is a bit more tricky. The reason is that the first argument that you use in `ifelse()` has length one, because `max()` returns a single number. The result of `ifelse()` has the same length as its first argument, that is, it is a single number as well. This number is then simply repeated to fill up the entire vector that is needed to for `mutatate()`. Therefore, you get the same value for all the rows in a group (i.e., all the rows in a year).

Let me demonstrate this with an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
ifelse(max(df$x), df$y, NA)
[1] 4
```

As you see, only the first value of `y` is returned by `ifelse()`. If the result of `ifelse()` is assigned to a column of `df`, then that value is simply repeated in order to fill up all the rows:

```
df$z <- ifelse(max(df$x), df$y, NA)
df
##   x y z
## 1 1 4 4
## 2 2 5 4
## 3 3 6 4
```

This is exactly what happens in your code. You can solve it for instance by adding a column to your data frame that contains for each row the required correction of the week number:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
       group_by(yy_cal) %>%
       mutate(delta_ww = as.integer(max(ww_cal) == 53),
              ww_new = ww_cal - delta_ww) %>%
       select(-delta_ww)
```

Here, I also profit from the fact that a single value is repeated to fill up all the rows of a data frame. But this time it works, because the shift in weeks (`delta_ww`) *is* the same for all the rows in a given years, such that repeating is is the right thing to do.

The trick here is that `as.integer()` converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`. If `max(ww_cal)` is `53`, then the condition is `TRUE` and `delta_ww` is set to `1`. If `max(ww_cal)` is not `53`, `delta_ww` turns out to be `0`.

You could also do the same without the auxiliary column, but it was easier to explain the intermediate step by explicitly showing the column. But in case your interested, this gives the same:

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
       group_by(yy_cal) %>%
       mutate(ww_new = ww_cal -  as.integer(max(ww_cal) == 53))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!!